# Excel VBA to update only one cell at one time

Tags: vba, excel

The motive of my code is to update one cell at a time with a comment who updated the cell at what time. But Instead of updating one cell at a time it's updating all my cells in K row. For Eg, if I want to update K10 its updating cell from K6 to K10 with the same value. Please help

```
Sub ActiveCell_Initial()
 strUserName = Application.UserName
 Range(ActiveCell, "K6").Value = " by " & strUserName & "@ " & Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what do you think that "K6" is doing in your code? Range(a, b) tells excel to select all cells between a and b inclusive, then if you change the value, it will change call cells in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update only the `ActiveCell`:

```
Sub ActiveCell_Initial()
    strUserName = Application.UserName
    ActiveCell.Value = " by " & strUserName & "@ " & Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question. Can i use timing from different time zone ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
range("K6:K10").calculate
```

does this help?

or maybe you merely meant to write this ? (not sure I catch the question)

```
Sub ActiveCell_Initial()
 strUserName = Application.UserName
 ActiveCell.Value = " by " & strUserName & "@ " & Now()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could not use the excel funciton NOW() at all and use the VBA function to get the datetime (i cant remember the commands) so that within the cell it says "by bob smith @ 1/1/2016 00:00:01" instead of "by bob smith @ NOW()"

alternatively you could copy the cell and special paste - values only it back which would give you the same result but most likely be more computationally hevy